# Dismiss side menu

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to dismiss the side menu view, which I implemented with the `SWRevealViewController`. How can I do this?

[image: dimiss]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you only have to call the properly method

```
self.revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true) //for left menu
self.revealViewController().rightRevealToggleAnimated(true) //for right menu I think this is what you want
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am also using swrevealviewcontroller for side menu. if u want side menu on any page simply paste following code in viewdidload, or if dont want side menu on some page simply delete the code.

if u want any help..comment below

```
if revealViewController() != nil {
    revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = screenBounds * 0.6875
    toggleButton.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}
```

Comment: i wanted to dismiss the side menu, because is blocking my sign in view, which i using push segue to show the sign in view, but the side menu wont dismiss